# Laptop battery replacement (MSI)

Tags: battery, windows-installer, spare-parts

So I bought a used (almost new) MSI laptop two weeks ago.
It is a GP62MVR-7RF Leopard Pro.

Everything is looking great on the outside & doing great on the inside. 1 problem, obviously : the battery discharges quite quickly.
I want to change it. The battery isn't the most common, but there are a few online.
And then I fall on this (German based) website that has 4 (!) different references for my laptop :
https://www.sparepartworld.com/msi/gp-serie/gp62/gp62mvr-7rf-serie/

All 4 have 6-cells and 10.8 voltage. Same for mine.

I got in touch with the customer's service : they did not give me much details, among which "all these batteries work for your computer" and "yes it can be shipped to France" (yep that's where I live).

My question was : Is a "compatible" (as said on the website) battery for a laptop is commonly working - and working good - as good and as long ? The price difference between compatible and original is quite a gap and I wanted to know why.

Also, there is no problem to put a 51Wh capacity on a 41Wh battery based laptop, right ?

Thank you very much for helping me !

Comment: Compatible just meant it will fit and work, main difference in laptop batteries is the quality of lion cells used in the manufacture, and there is no real way to compare them since this information is not published. Higher Wh on that battery just means they used higher capacity lion cells in manufacture, otherwise no difference.

Comment: Are there reviews on the quality of the product you can use ?  As @moab indicated you really can’t judge based on the amount of information you have available.

Comment: I have bought really cheap laptop replacement batteries and they work just fine, but they don't last as long as the high quality ones.

Comment: Ok, so it seems difficult to be sure if it works the same. Logic answer should be no, as it's twice cheaper. I'll call them again, maybe I can get a serial number or something. Thanks for the quick answers !

Comment: See this for more information on laptop batteries....https://superuser.com/questions/203186/laptop-battery-technology?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the precious informations. I'm not sure if I'm willing to take the risk to buy the « cheap » battery... That'd be helpful to have feedback from people who bought unofficial batteries & match results. Maybe all the ones who did ended up disappointed. Maybe buying a battery not coming from an OEM is NEVER a thing to do ? What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

When they say it is compatible, they mean the battery's physical form is compatible.  That is, it will fit into your laptop.  It also means that electrically it is compatible.  That is, the rated voltage is that of your laptop's original battery.

The Watt-Hours (wh) rating specifies the battery's charge capacity.  The higher the Watt-Hours, the longer it will last.  For Lithium-Ion batteries, you generally see degradation of capacity after about a year or so of constant use.  The longer you use the battery, the less effective capacity it will have.  So even if you replace the old one with a battery of equivalent rated capacity, you should see an improvement.