# Laptop battery 10.8V vs 11.1V

Tags: laptop, battery, voltage

I've had my HDX 16 for about 3 years now, and I've been using the batteries quite intensively last year. I'm getting warnings about the battery needing to be replaced before boot and in Windows.

Searching "HDX 16 Batteries" on ebay yielded quite a few cheap batteries. My laptop is on many of the sellers' compatibility lists, but most of their batteries' voltages are 11.1V, while mine is 10.8V.

Is this going to affect my laptop? Or does it just mean that the max voltage that the battery can supply is 11.1V?

Comment: related [Laptop battery: is voltage really important to respect?](http://superuser.com/q/33207)

Comment: Small voltage differences like that (.3v) make no difference, I would buy a genuine HP battery for best performance, those el cheapo ones do not last and some are fire hazards.